# extract x/y value in cm from coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc

I would like to extract the x/y coordinate with cm as unit. below example extract it as pt.

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,3);
\path let \p1=(A) in node[draw,circle,inner sep=5pt,label=above:{\x1,\y1}] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How could I get 2,3 as the label?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fpeval`. The `\ptto` command wants the unit as the first mandatory argument, so you can use different ones. The optional argument is the number of decimal digits to round at.

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ptto}{O{2}mm}{%
  \fpeval{round((#3)/(1#2),#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
  \path let \p1=(A) in node[
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=5pt,
    label=above:{\ptto{cm}{\x1},\ptto{cm}{\y1}}
  ] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you want the length in scaled points…

```
\documentclass[border=4]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\ptto}{O{2}mm}{%
  \fpeval{round((#3)/(1#2),#1)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
  \path let \p1=(A) in node[
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=5pt,
    label=above:{\ptto[0]{sp}{\x1},\ptto[0]{sp}{\y1}}
  ] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, how to understand `{O{2}mm}` and `(1#2)`?

Comment: @lucky1928 `O{2}` means that the command accepts an optional argument with default value 2 (the precision); the second argument is expected to be a unit such as `cm`, `mm`, `pt`, `in`, and the code tells LaTeX to divide the third argument by 1 unit. In the two examples, the code becomes “divide by 1cm” and “by 1sp” respectively.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, math}
\makeatletter
% transform a dimension (in pt) into a dimensionless number
\newcommand{\strippt}{\strip@pt\dimexpr}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
  \path let \p1=(A),
  \n1 = {\x1*1pt/1cm},
  \n2 = {\y1*1pt/1cm},
  in
  node[draw, circle, inner sep=5pt,
  label=above:{\strippt(\n1),\strippt(\n2)}] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\pgfmathparse` to remove units. The conversion factor from points to centimeters is .03514. You can use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to avoid rounding errors.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (2,3);
\path let \p1=(A) in node[draw,circle,inner sep=5pt,label=above:{\pgfmathparse{.03514*\x1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult},\pgfmathparse{.03514*\y1}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}] at (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or just divide by 1cm.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Good point.